# Flutter Unit Test - Expect difference between SuccessState<dynamic> and SuccessState<NetworkResponse>

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing, types

I'm trying to make unit test for my app but I get some issues with the expect() function.

This is my test:

```
test('User should register.', () async {
  final _response = await _api.register(mockSuccessfullRegisterUser);
  mockSuccessfullLoginUser = User(email: mockSuccessfullRegisterUser.email, password: mockSuccessfullRegisterUser.password);
  print(mockSuccessfullLoginUser.email);
  expect(_response.runtimeType, SuccessWithTokenResponseState);
});
```

My _response can return multiple types of responses like: SuccessWithTokenState, ErrorState, …
The expect function gives me this error:

```
TestFailure (Expected: Type:<SuccessWithTokenResponseState<dynamic>>
  Actual: Type:<SuccessWithTokenResponseState<NetworkResponse>>
)
```

Shouldn't SuccessWithTokenResponseState be equal to SuccessWithTokenResponseState?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

```
expect(_response.runtimeType is SuccessWithTokenResponseState, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a generic type without additional type it's fallback to `Type<dynamic>` try to use the correct type that you expect

```dart
expect(_response.runtimeType, SuccessWithTokenResponseState<NetworkResponse>);
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. It tells me the following: The operator '<' isn't defined for the type 'Type' and The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'Type'. It doesn't let me be more specific :/

Comment: `Type<dynamic>` is just an example, it's not pointing to a real type, you just have to replace your expect result from `SuccessWithTokenResponseState` to `SuccessWithTokenResponseState<NetworkResponse>` because `SuccessWithTokenResponseState` is a generic type and using it without `<>` will fallback to `SuccessWithTokenResponseState<dynamic>` and this is why you get the error.

Comment: It doesn't let me do it, it gives me an error when I start typing the greater than and lesser than signs it just gives me an error. It doesn't let me specify from SuccessWithTokenState to SuccessWithTokenState<NetworkResponse>.